# vuejs push tags separately to input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have tags input which the data are separated by commas (,) and in edit page i'd like to show each of them separably. (separate based on comma's)'

#### Sample

`data`

```
here, goes, testing,tags,check,this,out
```

`current result`

[image: onw]

`What I want it to be`

[image: two]

## Code

```
fetchData() {
  axios
    .get('/api/admin/settings/'+this.$route.params.id, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')
      }
     })
  .then(response => {
    this.form.tags.push(response.data.seo.tags) // here is my data returning to input (image #1)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log('error', error);
  });
},
```

any idea?

## Update

`html`

```
<el-form-item label="SEO Tags">
    <el-select
        style="width:100%"
        v-model="form.tags"
        multiple
        filterable
        allow-create
        default-first-option
        placeholder="Please input your seo tags (type + hit enter)">
    </el-select>
</el-form-item>
```

`script`

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            dialogImageUrl: '',
            dialogVisible: false,
            site_url: process.env.MIX_APP_URL,
            form: {
                name: '',
                tagline: '',
                logo: '',
                favicon: '',
                title: '',
                tags: [],
                description: '',
                photo: '',
                _method: 'PUT',
            },
        }
    },
    created () {
        this.fetchData()
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData() {
            axios
                .get('/api/admin/settings/'+this.$route.params.id, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')
                }
                })
            .then(response => {
                this.form.tags.push(response.data.seo.tags) // here is my data returning to input (image #1)
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('error', error);
            });
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: What string function in JavaScript allows you to split a string based on some separator? Then what array operation allows you to combine two different arrays? What have you tried other the code above?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky must of your questions i didn't understand but i'll update my question with more detail give me a min please

Comment: You can split a string using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split . You can combine two arrays using concat https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat . Try using those two methods to solve your issue.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky updated. also is not 2 arrays is only 1 array nothing to combine just splitting the result

Comment: If you split the string it becomes an array. Then it looks like data form tags is an array. So that would make two arrays.

Comment: what do you suggest now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting the data using string split then pushing the resulting array of items:

```
this.form.tags.push(...response.data.seo.tags.split(','))
```